# My stove has 4 wires coming out from the back

Tags: electrical

The stove has 4 wires coming out from the back. 1 black.  1 red. 1 white.  1 ground. The wall socket has 3 holes . 1 black.  1 white.  1 ground.  Can i put a plug that matches the  wall outlet on to the stove and how do i wire it correctly.

Comment: Is this a new stove that has an owner's manual with it? If so it may tell you what to do if you have a three wire receptacle. It makes a difference if the three wires are hot1, hot2, and neutral; or hot1, hot2, and ground. Probably you have the former and that is what you would need. What size breaker is feeding this circuit? What size does the owner's manual say the stove requires?

Comment: Shoot us a picture of what's in the wall, there are a couple of things it can be.

Comment: Can you give us a photo of the outlet box?  Is this a freestanding range/stove, or a built-in appliance?

Comment: You could replace the 3-wire receptacle with the 4-wire one which your power cord would plug into. To do this you would have to install a ground wire that would go up into the attic and connect to the heavy bare copper ground there or you could run a new ground all the way to the panel. This ground would not have to follow the route of the existing cable for the dryer. First you must determine if the wires in the cable are heavy enough for this range.